# CTRL_C_EVENT vs CTRL_BREAK_EVENT vs TerminateProcess on Windows

Tags: windows

I have seen plenty of discussions about Windows' TerminateProcess API. Also, I have learned that there are CTRL_C_EVENT and CTRL_BREAK_EVENT events.

My question is, what is the difference between them?

Comment: CTRL_C_EVENT is triggered by typing the Ctrl+C keys on the keyboard, it can be disabled by calling SetConsoleMode().  CTRL_BREAK_EVENT is triggered by typing Ctrl+Break, it cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

[`TerminateProcess` is insta-death](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=102304). The process won't see it coming and will just blink out of existence without ever knowing what hit it:

> [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) is the low-level process killing function. It bypasses DLL_PROCESS_DETACH and anything else in the process. Once you kill with TerminateProcess, no more user-mode code will run in that process. It’s gone. [Do not pass go. Do not collect $200.](https://web.archive.org/web/20081203232109/http://www.bartleby.com/66/76/15776.html)
>
> *~ [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) (I updated the links though)*

Contrarily, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break are handled as signals<sup>1</sup> and can be reacted upon. These key combinations trigger the corresponding signals, but there is also a function [`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) that can be used to trigger them<sup>2</sup>.

They are handled a bit differently from each other though. Ctrl+Break is *always* handled as signal, while Ctrl+C is *by default* handled as signal but applications may change this behavior to have it treated as regular keyboard input or ignored entirely. The details of how this is achieved are explained [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

"Handled as signals" means the following:

> The system creates a new thread in each client process to handle the event. The thread raises an exception if the process is being debugged. The debugger can handle the exception or continue with the exception unhandled.

...and:

> [A console control handler is] An application-defined function used with the [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) function. A console process uses this function to handle control signals received by the process. When the signal is received, the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the function.

There are default [console control handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-control-handlers) installed, but you are free to change them. The defaults will react on both Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break with process termination, but using [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) and not `TerminateProcess`. Unlike the use of `TerminateProcess` which constitutes an immediate rugpull, this *will* give certain cleanup operations in the process a chance to run before fully terminating it, such as `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` handlers in [`DllMain` functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) and [TLS callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#tls-callback-functions).

References and further reading:

- [CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK signals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals)
- [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler)
- [HandlerRoutine callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine)
- [Console Control Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-control-handlers)
- [Terminating a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-process)

---

<sub>**Footnotes:**</sub>

<sub>**1:** In a broad sense, "handled as signal" just means "there can be some user-supplied function that gets notified about this event and is allowed to act upon it as desired". Note that signals in a generalized way as you know them from *nixes don't exist as a concept in Windows. In some places docs refer to *nix-like signal names such as `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK` in this case but this is probably intended just to make it easier to understand if you come from a *nix background. There are different events that can happen in different contexts and they have different ways for reacting to them. Here we are talking about console events that a console control handler can receive (those Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break "signals" would show up in the console control handler's `fdwCtrlType` argument as `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, but console control handlers can handle other events as well, such as `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`), but other things that in a *nix world would also be a "signal" are handled in entirely different ways - for example an access violation which would be `SIGSEGV` in *nix would require an [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-unhandledexceptionfilter) to be handled, and there is no concept of a `SIGTERM` at all (it depends on the type of program you want to ask to terminate - in case of a GUI program the closest thing is sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to the main window if you can figure out what window that is, in case of a background service that's registered with the Windows service manager there is a dedicated "stop" command, in case of a console program it can be the console close event that's also triggered when you click the close button of the console window, etc.). So don't try to apply your knowledge about what signals do on other OSes here.</sub>

<sub>**2:** For this to work, the caller needs to be in the same console process group as the receiver, however. So, if you want to send this from an external process, you first need some trickery such as having a helper process whose sole job is to attach itself to the console of the target and then trigger the event "from the inside".</sub>

Comment: What signals do you mean exactly by saying "Contrarily, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break are handled as signals and can be reacted upon. These key combinations trigger the corresponding signals, ..."? Do you mean SIGINT and SIGBREAK, right?

Comment: In the Microsoft docs, they are sometimes titled `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` and in one place referred to as `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK`, but in most explanatory texts and comments in the docs they are simply called `Ctrl+C signal` and `Ctrl+Break signal` so that's what I used here as well. At the end of the day, it means "the things that a console control handler sees in `fdwCtrlType` as `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`", since actual process signals don't really exist as a concept in Windows as they do on *nixes.

Comment: I added a footnote about this now.